# Tag merge tsql and t-sql

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tagging

As per the title, the [tsql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tsql) and [t-sql](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/t-sql) tags should be merged, synonymed or otherwise brought together.

Hmmm, while trying to post this with just the above line, which is all the question needs, I got

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

Gotta love dumb and inflexible algorithms.

Comment: Good point......

Comment: It probably needed more cowbell

Comment: I was thinking the other end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The merge has been completed, and the thesarus updated. So mote it be.